# Socket communication between UWP and multiple platforms

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, uwp, webrtc

I want to implement Socket communication between UWP and multiple platforms.

Here, UWP acts as a server,
Multiple platforms each act as a client.

Share the UWP application screen in real time
Conduct voice chat
Receive WebCam screens from multiple clients
We want to implement interactive screen sharing, voice chat, and message chat.

It would be nice to think of it as a teleconference application.

How to send and receive data through simple socket communication
WebRTC, WebSocket, etc.
I have various concerns.

What is the best way to do it?

Also, is there a way to speed up development?
UWP is developed in C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP provide `StreamSocket` api to  communicate between apps, `StreamSocket` and a `StreamSocketListener` sending and receiving data over TCP to form an echo client and server. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#samples) is official document that you could refer. And UWP also provide [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket) that send the simple string value with streamsocket.

Comment: thank you.
I have already referenced the examples and samples.
For loopback processing, communication was attempted from different devices and the server actually received the client's string. Currently, we are testing for real-time communication in both directions.
Is real-time sharing of screen screens effective through StreamSocket?

Comment: Yep, you could load the screen recording stream and send it with `StreamSocket`.